# Easy admin : add checkbox or a button to display listAction

Tags: symfony

i'm new to Symfony (SF 3)/

i'm trying to put a checkbox or a button in an easy admin panel listAction to display connected or disconnected users in a list.
What i want to do is: i load my users list with only connected users, and when i click on checkbox "display all users", to reload the list with all users, disconnected and connected.

I don't know if i have to override listAction() and how, or just using createListQueryBuilder with an ajax call.

I have try this in my controller

```
protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
    {
        $response = parent::createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, 'ASC', 'name', $dqlFilter);

        if ($this->request->query->get('connected') == 'all') {
            $response->Where('entity.connected in (0, 1)');
        } else {
            $response->Where('entity.connected = 0 ');
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

In my twig :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="connected">Display all users</b><br>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>

   {% block body_javascript %}
   {% if 'list' == app.request.get('action') %}
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
           $('#connected').click(function(event) {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '/?entity=user&action=list&connected=all',
                   data: {
                       'connected': 'all',
                        },
               success: function (data) {
                   alert('it worked');
               },
               error: function () {
                   alert('it broke');
               },
               complete: function () {
                   alert('it completed');
               }
           });
           });
       });
```

I'm a little lost and I can't get anywhere.

can you guide me ?

Samantha

Comment: Out of curiosity: if you are new in using Symfony, why did you start with Symfony 3? The current LTS version is 4.4, and 5.1 is about to be released in some weeks

Comment: I know but this is the version used by my enterprise for this project. Normally it is planned to migrate to the v4 in few months.... But i don't decide ! ^^